# Exclude objective c file from public access in Swift module

Tags: objective-c, swift, module

I have a module in one of my projects that exposes a Swift interface, but in the module it needs to use an objective c class.  I don't want to expose this class publicly.  I can't figure out how to do this.  In order to use the objective c file, I have to import it into the umbrella header.  But when I do, Xcode is forcing me to make both the umbrella header and import public in order to compile...  How can I use the objective c file privately in the module without exposing it publicly?

I apologize if this has already been answered.  I've searched through about a dozen SO questions and read the Apple Docs.  I feel as though I'm missing something right in my face but damn.. I'm just not seeing it.